# Mis-typed URL with ' /' at the end causing IIS errors

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, redirect

Where in the IIS/ASP.NET pipeline can I check to see if the incoming url ends with a space and a slash (the offending entry loooks like this:'/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz.aspx /1')?  This is causing errors on our production server.  If I run it locally, Chrome gives me a too many redirects warning. Is there a way I can trap this or remove the ' /'?

Answer (score 0):

Found an acceptable answer.  Checking for a malformed url - !(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) - in the Application_Error event gives me the control I need